# Import the android support library

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I'm completely new to android and I'm trying some stuff. But there is a problem that I can't resolve. I'm trying to import some android support library and even if it seems like I did it properly by adding google() to my Gradle build, and by clicking Sync Now there is an error. I even used the project structure manager to add the dependencies and it still appears red.
Here is my build.gradle module file :

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.avoidspleen.exossupspe"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    // Appears red from now
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    // End of red
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

I'm using JetBrains toolbox to update Android Studio version 4.1.2.

Comment: You are trying to use two different versions of `appcompat`, along with a long-since-replaced `design` library. Remove the two lines that are showing red. And focus on learning from materials that are are less than three years old.

Comment: Thank you I'll do that